# can't run adv in windows 10

Tags: android, android-emulator, intel, haxm

I'm using Lenovo W540 laptop OS windows 10.
When I tried to run an android emulator, I get following error:

[image]

When I tried to install HAXM from SDK manager I can see a message like it is not compatible with windows. as follow:-

[image]

How can I run emulator in windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) manually from the following link. After installation, I run emulator usually. It worked fine.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager